# Where is the Java "jar" function

Tags: java, jar

I'm looking to make a jar file out some Java code using `jar [options] [name] [files]` from the command line but it's not recognized.

According to [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) Jar is part of the JDK. I have both 7 and 8 installed. How do I run the jar function?

I don't have a C:/Java that the Oracle documents show. I've tried running jar from within the JDK directories and with admin rights.

*I'm not putting params in yet, want to check I can at least find the jar function first.*

[image: Running jar from JDK directory]
[Running jar from JDK directory(1.8) http://puu.sh/eoer7/4fcd0ce63c.png](http://puu.sh/eoer7/4fcd0ce63c.png)
[Running jar from System32 http://puu.sh/eoe3X/076d79b4e4.png](http://puu.sh/eoe3X/076d79b4e4.png)

Comment: Likely in the <jdK>/bin directory

Comment: How are you running the java compiler (`javac`)?  It should work the same way.

Comment: Also, make sure the JDK/bin directory is in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

You have displayed two installations of the Java Runtime Environment (or JRE). You need to install a Java Developer Kit (or JDK), to get `jar`. Set your `JAVA_HOME` to the installation directory of the JDK, and add it to your `PATH`.

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

Also, [Using JAR Files: The Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) says (in part) *JAR files are packaged with the ZIP file format*, and you can use tools that can read and write ZIP files to work with them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the JDK installed. I use Eclipse (because I have to at Uni) and clicking my JDK directory comes up with C:/Program Files/... location.

Comment: Your attached images show JRE locations... if you are sure you have JDK installed - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308895 ;) (it should be in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version`).

Comment: I've noticed that now. Eclipse seems to use the JRE to compile and run and not JDK which confused me. PS - perhaps update your link as that's for XP ;)

Comment: Well the link was meant more as a sarcasm. Eclipse has its own compiler, so maybe that is why it works.

Comment: Eclipse also has its' internal "`Java > Installed JRE`" settings (which usually point to a JDK).